# UITextfield Exit

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I've a problem with a textfield in a custom cell.
I created a **EditingDidEnd** function for open a new view with a tableview with different possiblities to choose for the textfield.

Par example: you write mister in the field an a view shows all names with mister...

Then I click on the user I wish, then the view is closing. The problem is now, that the textfield stay in the edit mode. How can I exit the edit mode? And if I click on done on the keyboard, the procedure restarts....

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `[textField resignFirstResponder]`. That will end the text field editing, and dismiss the keyboard.